# My Neural Network gives a wrong prediction when I specify more nodes

Tags: neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, python, prediction, training-error

I recently got interested in neural nets. After reading a bunch I tried to make one in python using numpy. I fed in some sample input and output data.

When I train the neural net and and then ask it to predict the output from the same input that I used to train it, it gives the correct output when I specify the number of nodes as 2 or 3. But when I increase that to 10, it gives me the wrong output.

It seems like an error in my code which leads to this, but I cannot figure out what it is. The full code can be found here: https://github.com/HariharanJayashankar/simple_neural_net/blob/master/simple_neural_net.py.

But the relevant training code is:

```
import numpy as np

# Definitining functions


def sigmoid(x):  # pass a normal function here to get its sigmoid transformation
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


def sigmoid_deriv(x):  # pass a sigmoid function in here to get its derivative
    return sigmoid(x) * sigmoid(1 - x)


def run(x, O, W_1, W_2, b_1, b_2, learning_rate):
    # x = input; W_1 = matrix of weights; Y = output
    # forward prop
    A_0 = x.T
    Z_1 = np.dot(W_1, A_0) + b_1
    A_1 = sigmoid(Z_1)
    Z_2 = np.dot(W_2, A_1) + b_2
    Y = (sigmoid(Z_2)).T
    # backward prop
    # Following MSE as our loss function
    e = sigmoid(Z_2) - O.T  # overall error for the network
    # error signals (calculated according to MSE)
    d_2 = e
    d_1 = np.dot(W_2.T, d_2) * sigmoid_deriv(Z_1)
    # Update rule
    up_b1 = learning_rate * d_1
    up_b2 = learning_rate * d_2
    up_W_1 = learning_rate * np.dot(d_1, A_0.T)
    up_W_2 = learning_rate * np.dot(d_2, A_1.T)
    return Y, (up_W_1, up_W_2, up_b1, up_b2)

def train(x, O, W_1, W_2, b_1, b_2, n_iter, learning_rate):
    for i in range(n_iter):
        Y, upd = run(x, O, W_1, W_2, b_1, b_2, learning_rate)
        W_1 = - upd[0]
        W_2 = - upd[1]
        b_1 = - upd[2]
        b_2 = - upd[3]
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print(i)
            print((1 / np.size(O, 0)) * np.dot((Y - O).T, (Y - O)))

    return (W_1, W_2, b_1, b_2)
```

The number of nodes comes into play here:

```
w_1 = np.random.rand(n_nodes, np.size(inp, 1))
w_2 = np.random.rand(np.size(out, 1), n_nodes)
b1 = np.random.rand(n_nodes, np.size(inp, 0))
b2 = np.random.rand(np.size(out, 1), np.size(out, 0))
```

Sorry if this was too verbose but I couldn't find another person who posted a similar problem (although there were problems of finding the optimal number of nodes).

My problem is that when I put in too many nodes (10 for example), the net fails to predict the output from the training example itself.

Comment: Have you tried to train it for longer? Have you checked how's network's prediction changes over time?

Comment: So I've used different number of iterations to test it out along with different number of nodes. The loss function calculated as MSE gets suck at around 0.2, and this occurs quickly (before 20 iterations).
Additionally, increasing the number of nodes, as far as i can see, has a pretty random effect on this loss. But all of it hovers around 0.2-0.24

Comment: Did you write this statement correctly - `W_1 = - upd[0]`? It looks like it should be `W_1 -= upd[0]`

Comment: @itdxer I feel really stupid. Yes this fixes it. The loss is super low now and variations in iternations and nodes are working as one would expect.
i feel super embarassed now